# astra as3 panel layout

Tags: actionscript-3, yahoo-astra

I'm trying to create a layout not too different from the [feed reader sample](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/layout-containers/examples/FeedReader/FeedReader.html).

The problem I'm having is that I'm finding the documentation unclear. There are so many different types of layouts that I don't know which one to use when.

In the example, on the right side there are a few horizontal panels:

- [feedToolbar(HboxPane)]
- [feedItemsGrid(Datagrid)]
- [filterToolbar(HBox)]

*this does not include the details panel and the resize handle.*

I would like to swap the DataGrid with my custom content which is basically a sprite. The problem I have is that I cannot just include a sprite, because it does some funky resizing. I would like the scroll bar to appear when the content is too tall, and have have the same skin for the background as the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shortly after posting...

I've tried `BaseScrollPane`, a class that DataGrid extends, but I couldn't use addChild.
I came across `FlowPane`, seems like it did the trick.